# Convert mm-dd-YY to Timestamp at Midnight UTC

Tags: date, timestamps

I need to convert a `mm-dd-YY` string to a UNIX timestamp for use with HubSpot's API. Said API requires that dates be set to midnight UTC.

I can convert the date using: `date -j -f "%m-%d-%Y" "01-20-2013" "+%s"` but how can I append the "midnight UTC" component to the output?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you perhaps explain where your "input" `dd-mm-YY` string comes from (program output, text file, ...), and through which processing chain you want to transfer it to the HubSpot API (i.e. shell script, compiled command, ...)

Comment: Please also would you indicate your local timezone. We can use this to convert back to UTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @stoney mentioned in his reply, the "midnight UTC" part needs to be in the input.

I see that you're using BSD date, so you're probably on macOS.

`date -j -u -f "%m-%d-%YT%T" "01-20-2013T00:00:00" "+%s"`

The `-u` option interprets the date as UTC, and the `%T` part in the format string lets the command also read the time, here explicitly set to midnight.

Comment: I've now learned that I actually need to provide the timestamp in _milliseconds_. Can I append something to the `01-20-2013T00:00:00` input so that the command will output milliseconds?

Answer (score 1):

date -d "2013-01-20T00:00:00+0000" +"%s"

There is no midnight utc in the output but in the input.